# how to stop body content showing over footer content and below

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete, overflow

i am using autocomplete text box, here based on dynamic value to exceed scroll bar ,if more then value show in text box  scroll bar automatically exceed in footer page and also two scroll bar displayed. if more value show in the text box  scroll bar should not exceed footer content,only displayed with in body container and also not show two scroll bar, so please help to me for this problem.

css code:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 28%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

autocomplte code :
areas data type is array , it contain multiple values

```
autocomplete({
    autoFocus : true,
    source : areas,
    selectFirst : true,
    select : function(event, ui) {
};
```

image[image]

Comment: instead giving max-height in % try some fixed value, like max-height:200px

Comment: max-height: 200px try this one but this not working thanks for your  commands

Comment: Here's is a fiddle in which max height seems to work fine -http://jsfiddle.net/uH5zb/ - how is it different than your code?

Comment: would better if you can create a working DEMO..

Comment: you get double sidebar because body and footer wrapper has overflow set to auto or scroll

Comment: actually before  i'am tried auto complete  without  use scroll but compare to now expand more in footer and below, thanks for your commands

Answer (score 0):

A sample code would be great in order to help, but from the attached image, I'm guessing that your *body container*'s parent has a fixed height while your *body container* has a **static** positioning.

If so, you'll need to change *body container*'s CSS position to **relative** and assign a fixed height to your `.ui-autocomplete` class:

```
.body-container {
    position: relative;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px; /* For example */
}
```

If you remove the fixed height from your *body container*'s parent, the second scrollbar should disappear. If you *MUST* keep the fixed height, then set overflow-y to **hidden**.